# How to get screen width in multiply window mode Android N?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, screen

Since Android N we have multiple window mode. 
I want to get the screen width (in pixel) when our activity is in this mode.
[image]

I tried this code, but it always returns the real size of device

```
 ((WindowManager) itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
```